# backbone.js doesn't render view with konacha

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, coffeescript, mocha.js, konacha

I want to do some DOM test for my backbone.js application with konacha. And I have read some entries about konacha below.

- https://github.com/markbates/informit_articles/blob/master/article_2_konacha/article_2_konacha.md
- http://www.slideshare.net/markykang/testing-javascriptcoffeescript-with-mocha-and-chai

These entries indicate that I should create a view and put it in the page object like below.

```
#= require spec_helper
describe "MyApp.Views.Relationships", ->
  beforeEach ->
  @view = new MyApp.Views.Relationships()
  @page.html(@view.el)
  console.log @view.el
```

**Problem:**
But console.log in the code above shows "undefined" for @view.el although the codes works fine in practice.

I really appliciate if someone can help me.

Here is some interested codes.

```
spec_helper.js.coffee
#= require application
#= require_tree ./support

mocha.ui('bdd')
mocha.ignoreLeaks()

beforeEach ->
  @page = $("#konacha")
  @sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()

afterEach ->
  @sandbox.restore()
```

```
views/users/relationships.js.coffee
class MyApp.Views.Relationships extends Backbone.View

  el: '#relation-form'
  template: JST['users/relationships']

  initialize: ->
    console.log "init"
    @render()
    console.log @el


  render: ->
    @img = $('#loading-image').html()
    $(@el).html(@template({img: @img}))
    this
```

```
relationships.jst.eco
<button class="btn" disabled="disabled"><%- @img %></button>
```

```
profile.html.erb(extracted)
   #snip#
            <% if signed_in? and @user != current_user %>
              <div id="relation-form" class="action-button"></div>
            <% end %>
   #snip#
    <script type="text/template" id="loading-image">
      <%= image_tag('ajax-loader.gif') %>
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        new MyApp.Views.Relationships()
      });
    </script>
```

what I want to do with these codes is to handle follow button like twitter.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Include the template the view requires in the spec itself. Something like:

```
#= require spec_helper
#= require templates/users/relationships

describe "MyApp.Views.Relationships", ->
    beforeEach ->
    @view = new MyApp.Views.Relationships()
    @page.html(@view.el)
    console.log @view.el
```

Or wherever your templates are located.

It is possible that the template will still be undefined. If that is the case it could be that the app is loaded before the template is. So if that is the case you could alternatively remove the require application in the spec_helper and just include the bits you are testing in each spec specifically.